# Looking for a package that aliases commands on multiple remote hosts using ssh

Tags: ssh, remote, command, remote-access, aliases

i would like to find a program that maintains a list of commands that can be aliased for different hosts. 
for example, we have a database server, and four web servers. a common task is to login to the admin server and restart mysql using

```
# ssh dbserver "service mysql restart"
```

then we restart each of the web servers by running

```
# ssh webserver1 "service apache2 restart"
# ssh webserver2 "service apache2 restart"
# ssh webserver3 "service apache2 restart"
# ssh webserver4 "service apache2 restart"
```

I would like to have an package that keeps track of these commands and i could run them as such:

```
# blah dbserver,webserver1-4 "restartServices"
```

then it would loop through each host listed and run the commands necessary to restart the services on those boxes.

Comment: adding information: we have over 2500 systems and remembering the list of commands to restart X service on Y system is cumbersome.

Comment: If you have 2500 systems then may I suggest, that you may be looking at this completely backwards, and instead you should be looking for something like puppet + mcollective.

Comment: Please include additional details in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: @Zoredache do you have an example of how mcollective would accomplish this?

Comment: I haven't actually used mcollective, just read a bit about it when I was reading through [Pro Puppet](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Puppet-James-Turnbull/dp/1430230576).  I deal with a smaller set, and I suspect far more diverse set of servers.  I am not sure mcollective would be as useful for what I am doing.  From what I understand basically allow you to issue commands to a group of system that you can specify based on a large number of facts provided by facter that can be filtered with regular expressions.  If you are interested, I suggest you grab a copy of the book I linked to.

Comment: I believe capistrano will do what i need, it is called namespacing

https://github.com/leehambley/capistrano-handbook/blob/master/index.markdown#namespacing-tasks

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own bash script for this.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh server 1 "service apache2 restart"
ssh server 2 "service apache2 restart"
ssh server 3 "service apache2 restart" etc....
```

Then just run the script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we have 2500 servers with random start and stop commands. It's extremely difficult to remember them all and i don't want to do them in the same order every time. for example, what if i only want to restart the dbserver and a couple of the web servers? I will add information to my post to clarify the requirements.

Comment: If you only want to restart the dbserver and a couple of the webservers, then... only restart the dbserver and a couple of the webservers.  You can do all *sorts* of things with shell scripts.

Comment: ... and if you want even more control, then use variables in the script to group multiple servers together and/or execute on stand-alone machines. Maybe something like ./run-my-script {server x} {server-group y}.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a few ways.

Perhaps the most simple way would be to use [pssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) (parallel ssh).

If your needs are more complex, you can use a framework like [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) or [MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/).

Comment: from what i can tell, pssh only will execute the same command on multiple systems. i'm looking for a command that helps keep a list of what commands i need to run. then using aliases i can use the same command to restart different services depending on which host i am trying to administer.

i've looked at fabric and it is interesting but seems like more of a 'batch' system? is there some tutorial you know of that shows how to use it more flexibly?

Comment: Well you gave a pretty irrelevant example then. In as large of an environment as you have, you're already *way* behind the game if you don't have this sorted already. As zoredache mentioned above, look into puppet and mcollective. You're going to need to do a large amount of customization regardless of what solution you choose.

Comment: "keep a list of what commands i need to run" -- that is the *very* definition of a shell script.

Comment: The example is exactly what i want.

I've looked at fabric a bit deeper now, and I still can't see a way to get it where i need it. With a fabfile.py set out like this:



    from fabric.api import run, env, roles
    
    env.roledefs = {
        'web': ['localhost'],
        'dns': ['172.25.16.55']
    }
    
    @roles('dns')
    def taskA():
        run('ls')
    
    @roles('web')
    def taskA():
        run('whoami')

Comment: the above did not format correctly, but what i am looking for is a way to get fabric to run the following command:


fab -R dns,web taskA


where taskA runs different commands on dns then it does web.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like what you want is [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/). It comes with a nice web interface, but also works just as well on the command line.

Comment: that looks promising, i will look into that. thanks.